# MySQL, Python: SELECT WHERE LIKE Query

Tags: python, mysql

I am creating a console interface to add, edit and view entries in a database of my video game collection. In the edit section I was adding a search function, in order to find the specific game. In the select query for the search I have variables for the table to pull from and the like condition.

For the select query I was using:

```
GameQuery = "SELECT Name, Sub_Name, Platform, Barcode, Edition, Overall_Condition, Region, Requirement, Optional FROM AllGames WHERE Name LIKE %s"
```

And then executed it with:

```
MediaCursor.execute(GameQuery, SearchCriteria)
```

But if I was to search for a game where the name included an apostrophe e.g. Tom Clancy's it would only execute ...LIKE %s as the apostrophe in the name cuts it off. I then tried to execute it with:

```
MediaCursor.execute(GameQuery,(SearchCriteria,))
```

Which happened to work for my situation. But I am unable to use a variable for the table name too, which I need.

I have tried to use:

```
GameQuery = "SELECT Name, Sub_Name, Platform, Barcode, Edition, Overall_Condition, Region, Requirement, Optional FROM %s WHERE Name LIKE %s"
```

With this execution:

```
MediaCursor.execute(GameQuery, TableName,(SearchCriteria,))
```

but it doesn't replace `%s` with the values.

I then tried to use a Python Tuple for this situation with the code

```
SearchCriteria = raw_input("Input The Game Name: ")
TableName = raw_input("Input The Platform: ")
qy = TableName, (SearchCriteria,)
GameQuery = "SELECT Name, Sub_Name, Platform, Barcode, Edition, Overall_Condition, Region, Requirement, Optional FROM %s WHERE Name LIKE %s" %qy
MediaCursor.execute(GameQuery)
```

but this just gave a **syntax error near )** in `MediaCursor.execute(GameQuery)`

Comment: What does your `SearchCriteria` look like?

Comment: Yes, add the following, get the output and report back:
print (GameQuery)  also, print(SearchCriteria) - Once you see what's inside you might answer your own question.

Comment: I printed GameQuery, SearchCriteria and TableName and they all gave the correct output. When the MediaCursor executed the query I get `right syntax to use near ''PS2' WHERE Name LIKE 'Tom Clancy\'s''`

Comment: I also tried to execute it as `MediaCursor.execute(GameQuery,(TableName,(SearchCriteria,)))` but this just gives the error **Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I put the `TableName` variable in the `GameQuery` line and executed it like this:

`GameQuery = "SELECT Name, Sub_Name, Platform, Barcode, Edition, Overall_Condition, Region, Requirement, Optional FROM " + TableName + " WHERE Name LIKE %s"`

`MediaCursor.execute(GameQuery,(SearchCriteria))`

However, thank y'all for the assistance.